# Is my kitchen wired in an incorrect way?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

There is a circuit in my kitchen that does not power any of the major appliances (Stove, fridge dishwasher, etc). The circuit only has 3 outlets. The 1st outlet is a 20amp GFCI, The 2nd outlet is a 20amp GFCI. The 3rd outlet is non-GFCI 15amp.

All 3 outlets work fine most of the time. In the winter, sometimes the 3rd outlet does not work. When it is not working I read the following voltage on my multimeter:

Outlet 1: 120v Hot to Neutral, 120v Hot to Ground 0v Neutral to Ground.

Outlet 2: 120v Hot to Neutral, 120v Hot to Ground 0v Neutral to Ground.

Outlet 3: **0v Hot to Neutral**, 120v Hot to Ground 0v Neutral to Ground.

The receptacles of all 3 outlets are shallow. None of the outlets use the "feed through" method. However, I don't see any pigtails either. So I'm assuming the outlets are spliced into the circuit somewhere behind the walls. The area of the kitchen is a recent addition by the previous owners. The walls are also thin. Not much space between the kitchen interior and the exterior of the house. Does my assumption seem correct? If so, is this safe? Is this a fire hazard?

I'm also assuming the reason the 3rd outlet working intermittently is because there may be a faulty or corroding connection to the 3rd outlet somewhere behind the walls. Does that seem like a likely cause of the intermittent outage in winter?

For Reference, All 3 outlets are wired exactly like this (No feed through or pigtails visible inside the receptacle)[image: Outlet diagram]

Comment: Problem could be at receptacle 2 or 3 (in wiring sequence, which may or may not be obvious without looking at the actual wiring). Key questions: 1 - When receptacle 3 is working, is it GFCI protected? You can check by pressing the test button on receptacles 1 and 2 (but only do one at a time). What you *should* find is that one of the other receptacles when GFCI is TESTed will turn off itself and receptacle 3, but *not* affect the other receptacle. Assuming that is indeed the case, turn off the breaker and pull out that receptacle (the one with the GFCI that turns off # 3) and # 3 and

Comment: take pictures of the wiring and upload them so we can figure it out.

Comment: The measurement for outlet 3 does not look right. Please check again.Maybe your probe is not making contact.

Comment: If there's wiring buried in the wall, all wiring is suspect. Junction boxes much be exposed. Look around everywhere for a box with a blanking plate over it, including possibly in the attic.

Comment: When taking pictures, check if they used the screws or the back stabs.  The neutral on #3 sounds like loose or broken connection if reading is correct, and back stabs is first suspect.

Comment: I would say the Neutral on #3 is defective, bad or intermediate contact. Start will pul test to make sure it is tight.

Comment: Agree about neutral, indicate poor contact either in "outlet" 3 or in "outlet" 2.  perhaps from "backstab" connection or loose screw. Get a plug-in receptacle tester. No reason to suspect splices outside boxes (in the wall) unless you pull the receptacles and see that must bethe case. Are you looking at the side screws and seeing no wires? Could be connected in back.

Comment: I tested the wires directly for the volt readings